# problem when round the corner of the picture with css in firefox and IE

Tags: css

I want to round the corner of my picture by using css in IE7,8 and Firefox.
I have try to use -moz-border-radius for Firefox but it just round only border not the picture.

Link to picture: http://i108.photobucket.com/albums/n33/ligthing_illuminate/problemwithcorner.png

and the css which I use is following:

```
.content p img {
   float:left;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width:780px; 
   border: 10px solid white;
   -moz-border-radius: 15px;
}
```

and in IE7,IE8 are not work with border-radius.
Anyone can help me?
Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`-mos-border-radius` is not supported in IE 7 or 8....you will need to revert to rounding images or [Nifty Corners](http://www.html.it/articoli/nifty/index.html) to implement rounded corners in IE 7 or 8

Comment: thanks you, And does it possible to make it round the corner of picture not round the border in firefox with -moz-border-radius?

Comment: You would need to specify two different pictures dynamically.  If using Mozilla load the non rounded picture.  If not Mozilla then load the rounded picture.  If I  were you I would do it all one way.  either use the rounded image.  Or use Nifty Corners.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to make the image itself have rounded corners.

But this could be helpful too maybe: http://www.devwebpro.com/25-rounded-corners-techniques-with-css/

Answer (score 0):

See the `-moz` part at the start of the `-moz-border-radius` CSS rule?

It means that this is a vendor specific extension (in this case for mozilla/firefox).

It is not supported on other browsers.

Comment: Thanks you. The problem that I found when use -moz in firefox is the picture which show you in link is not rounded in the corner. So, does it possible to make it round?